# Is it true that there is no algorithm to find the proof in the fitch proof system??

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I think it probably exists. This is because the fitch proof system for propositional logic and FOL is very simple. Although it may not be effective.  Can anyone tell me about such an algorithm?

Comment: Use [Tableaux method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux); it is very similar to Natural Deduction and offer a very simple proof procedure.

Comment: Obvously, the algorithm works "mechanically" for propositional logic, because truth table method allows us to solve the problem of checking if a formula is a *tautology*.

Comment: Not so for FOL, because the [problem of validity is *undecidable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability#Satisfiability_in_first-order_logic) for FOL.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. But can we translate the truth tree of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots ,\alpha_n,\alpha\}$ into the proof of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n \vdash \alpha$ in Natural Deduction.

Comment: For example, it is straightforward to (mechanically) transform any instance of the group word problem into a problem in FOL with a single binary function symbol; yet the group word problem is undecidable in general.